# JIRA: Filter all issues that has subtasks of a particular component

Tags: jira, jql

I want to filter out all issues that has subtasks but of a particular component. The following works but it returns all stories with subtasks.

```
project = ABCDEF123 AND issuetype in (Story) and issueFunction in hasSubtasks()
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work, returning nothing

```
project = ABCDEF123 AND issuetype in (Story) and issueFunction in subtasksOf("component = xyz1234")
```

So I want JIRA to return all stories with subtasks and the component of that subtask is xyz1234.

I do not want to use any plugins.Hope you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've worked it out

```
project = ABCDDEF123 AND issuetype in (Story) AND issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("component in (xyz1234)")
```

Comment: should mention that this requires scriptrunner

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are using *Adaptivist ScriptRunner* plugin for JIRA.
[Documentation](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_subtasksof) says, that subquery returns parents of the subtasks. It looks like you have to swap the query for the subtasks and parents:

`issuefunction in subtasksOf(project = ABCDEF123 AND issuetype in (Story)) and "component = xyz1234"`